# Client side searching of a table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search

Assume I have a standard HTML table structure like:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-condensed">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Added</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="1a0daa2734" class="item">
        <td><a href="/view/1a0daa2734">Item Number 1</a></td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>8/1/2012 10:18:34 PM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="b1ff6e0ac" class="item">
        <td><a href="/view/b1ff6e0ac">Item Number 2</a></td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>8/2/2012 5:48:54 PM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="edd8b70893" class="item">
        <td><a href="/view/edd8b70893">Item Number 3</a></td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>8/13/2012 3:55:41 PM</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to write client side searching with jQuery. Basically I have a search box with an id of `search-items`.

```
    $("#search-items").bind("keyup paste", function() {
        var searchText = $("#search-items").val(); 

        $(".item").each(function() {
             //???
        });
    });
```

What is the best way to take the search value of `search-items` and find the **NON-MATCHES** inside of the tbody? I want the non-matches, because those are the elements I will hide.

It should only search inside the first two `td` elements, so the `name` and `type` columns, **not added**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code will try and match the values as you type them to either column1 or 2.

```
$("#search").on("keyup paste", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
    var $rows = $("table tr");

    if(value === ''){
        $rows.show();
        return false;
    }

    $rows.each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {

            $row = $(this);

            var column1 = $row.find("td:first a").html().toUpperCase();
            var column2 = $row.find("td").eq(1).text().toUpperCase();

            if ((column1.indexOf(value) > -1) || (column2.indexOf(value) > -1)) {
                $row.show();
            }
            else {
                $row.hide();
            }
        }
    });
});​
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/eCM9N/) - Searching your table by column 1 and 2 values individually (not added)

I'm sure there is a much more efficient way of writing it but this should get you started.

Comment: When you said `I want the non-matches, because those are the elements I will hide.` I made a bit of an assumption. The code I posted will hide the complete row if not matched and if matched leave it visible. However, if you wanted the result returned first it would only be a minor tweak. Or if this is not at all what you were looking for, let me know and I will update it with the required changes then.

Comment: Thanks, but you have to start searching at the start, it should be able to start searching anywhere, for example: search for `umb`

Comment: @Justin: I updated the fiddle and code in the post. The search will now match the value entered rather than just check if it starts with it. Basically the same as a `contains` See the updated fiddle and let me know if this is closer to what you needed. Currently the search is not case sensitive but if you want it to be it's a minor tweak.

Comment: Thank you very much. One small thing, is it possible, instead of simply showing and hiding, can I do a `slideUp` and `slideDown` effect with a 300ms time? I tried it, but the effect does not show. Probably because we need to callback when finished?

Comment: @Justin: I wasn't able to get slide to work either. Maybe it is to do with it being a `<tr>`, not sure really. However, I updated the fiddle to use `$row.show(500);` and `$row.hide(500);`. That will add some fading animation. You can also create 2 classes for styles and then using jQuery UI's `switchClass()` to toggle them applying some basic transitional animation. If I have time later I might `fork` the fiddle to show you an example of that too.

Comment: @Justin: I played around with `switchClass()` but tables are just not as nice to animate. I had added that the borders disappear of the item as it hides but when making visible again it just appears again without animation. `<tr>` tags are quite stubborn it seems. So far the best I was able to manage was what I mentioned in the previous comment, using show/hide with a duration.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this?

```
function escapeRegex(value) {
    return value.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
}

$(function() {
    $("#search-items").bind("keyup paste", function() {
        var searchText = $("#search-items").val(),
            regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(searchText), "gi"),
            $items = $(".item").show();

        if (searchText) {
            $items.each(function() {
                var $tds = $("td", this).slice(0, 2), // only the first two columns
                    text = $tds.text();

                if (text.search(regex) === -1) {
                    $(this).hide();
                }

            });
        }
    });
});​
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Pc7Nk/1/

*The `escapeRegex` function was shamelessly stolen from [jQueryUI autocomplete's source code.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js#L559)*

Answer (score -1):

Going row by row, find the first td (you can also add n number of td elements you want to match against if you like. .text() will return a string, using the string object .search method, you are returning the index of the first match, -1 is returned if there was no match, so we hide the row.

```
$("#search-items").bind("keyup paste", function() {
    var searchText = $("#search-items").val(); 

    $(".item").each(function() {
         var $this = $(this)
         if ($this.find('td:first-child').text().search(searchText) === -1) {
             $this.hide()
         }
    });
});
```